# Creating Invoices

Tags: c#, sql, invoices

I'm attempting to create a "point of sale" program. Where the user can enter stock into a database, as well as customers etc. I want to be able to create a "Job" where I can enter several stocked items from the database, enter customer information, click save, and then when I click sold it turns it into a printable invoice. 
I use this software at work :
http://www.mamsoftware.com/en/autopart-tyres
And would like to do something similar to the picture (although its not very clear) But you basically type the stock item into it, it finds the price etc from the database, and you then assign a customer to it, and click "save" or "invoice".
Would I have to create a new datatable and save it into the database for each one, assign a unique number to it (for reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will be better to store all the data in a database. 
At least is my point of view! 
And you will be able to export as excel if you want too.

Comment: Would I be able to create a datatable for each invoice, if you get where I'm coming from ?

Comment: I think that you can create a table called invoices, and each invoice will be a row. 
Then, you can retrive from the database all the invoices for a client, and show as you want ;)

Comment: But I'd need to add multiple stocked items to it, including prices and quantities etc, Would it work that way or would I need to create a new table for each "job"?

Comment: I think that you can add another table, then add in that other table the stocked items, with an ID which reference to each invoice in the invoice table ;) 
This way you will be able to retrive all the stocked items with the same id that the invoice

Comment: Do you know of any tutorials for what I need to do ?

Comment: mmmm, nop, so sorry! But i think that if you know something about SQL will be not hard for you to create ;)

Comment: True, So I can create a new table for each job, add the stocked items as needed, add a customer, then create a unique reference number for it, and access it from another table to be viewed, printed etc?

Comment: Yeah ;) you got the idea! ;)